# Searching for Birth Record or 1900 Census, Marie Paris b 28 Mar 1885 St. Louis, Missouri

Tags: census-records, birth-records, missouri

Can you help me to find either a Birth Record or a 1900 Census Record for Marie Paris who was born 28 Mar 1885 at St Louis, Missouri?

Marie's parents are:  Isabella Washington (Benden - div) Paris aka Belle and Louis A Paris.  Louis and belle married in New Jersy in 1884 and divorced by 1893.

Marie married Paul Pflager in 1906 and Wayne Poston c 1928.   One daughter born of the union with Paul Pflager.  Marie frequently mis-stated her age in documentation; 1885 is the correct year.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Ancestry tree, I'm thinking this 1900 St. Louis, MO census record is at least a possibility (Belle Brewer and children William & Pansey):

https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:S3HT-DBG3-8MR?wc=9BQ5-J4G%3A1030552401%2C1034846101%2C1035572301%3Fcc%3D1325221&cc=1325221

The names, ages, and locations are the same or similar, and maybe Pansy was a nickname?